# Why I failed to compile a sctp program in Linux?

Tags: linux, undefined-reference, sctp

First I install sctp on Ubuntu 12.04
    *sudo apt-get install libsctp-dev lksctp-tools*
Then in my .c file,I include :

```
#include < netinet/in.h >
#include < netinet/sctp.h >
#include < sys/socket.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < unistd.h >
```

howerver,when I compiled with gcc,the result is:

```
 undefined reference to `sctp_recvmsg'
 undefined reference to `sctp_get_no_strms'
 undefined reference to `sctp_sendmsg'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Show your compilation command, ans some part of your source code.

Comment: Show the `gcc` command you are using to compile your program. Remember that the order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really compile with `gcc temp.c -o temp` then you are not linking any libraries (except the default `libc.6.so`), and you need some additional argument to `gcc` ; perhaps try to compile with

```
 gcc -Wall -g temp.c -lsctp -o temp
```

Once your program is debugged with the help of the `gdb` debugger and you consider it to be bug-free, you may ask the compiler to optimize it using

```
 gcc -Wall -O2 temp.c -lsctp -o temp
```

The order of program arguments to `gcc` is important and significant.

Answer (score 0):

centos: yum install lksctp-tools-devel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).